# GWT: How to implement file download

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I am new to GWT and general web application.

I am making a GWT web application. One functionality it provides is to download file by clicking a button on the web page. Unfortunately, the file itself does not physically located on the server side. Server side needs to grab it through a REST call to another web service to get a InputStream of the file.

My question is that:

1. How can I pass the stream to the client side so that the browser can start to download?
2. Do I have to write the file physically on the server before start this?

Many thanks

EDIT: I have found this example:
[How to use GWT when downloading Files with a Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937126/how-to-use-gwt-when-downloading-files-with-a-servlet)

In this example, the file is physically located on the server side. The file I got from the web service via a stream is very large and I don't want to save them on my GWT server side. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using pushing your inputstream to the outputstream  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725198/how-to-make-user-can-download-file-in-client-side-google-web-toolkit/

Comment: Check this out dear, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458525/how-to-show-file-in-gwt-client-side-instead-of-downloading/15467029#15467029

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use a servlet like the example above. Just make sure you set the header and the file name to be of the appropriate type. (The filename must end in the proper ending)

```
// process the data (In your case go get it)
byte[] data = generateReturnBuffer();
// do not cache
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");  
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");  
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
// content length is needed for MSIE
response.setContentLength(data.length);
// set the filename and the type
response.setContentType("application/pdf");  
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "fileName.pdf");  
ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
out.write(data);
out.flush();
```

where the response is the servlet HttpServletResponse.
[Look here for the valid mime types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types).
At some point you will need to store the data in either a file or in memory since certain versions of internet explorer require the file length.

Answer (score 0):

Convert inputstream to preffered format and create tempfile

```
File f = File.createTempFile("tmp", "yourformat(.txt)", new File("C:/"));



 // deletes file when the virtual machine terminate
 f.deleteOnExit();
```

create temp file to dowload user and , it automatically deleted  when exit .

Comment: The query specifically mentions not to save file on server side as it is large.